# Transpose `matrix[:,mask]` to `matrix[mask,:]` by using only number `0` and `1`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix, mean

I want to write only one function to calculate true mean (don't count the zero element when averaging numbers in row or column) of each row or column of `matrix`. I try to control whether it is by-row or by-column calculation using `axis` parameters as `1` or `0`, respectively.

This is the function for by-column calculation

```
def true_mean(matrix, axis):
  countnonzero = (matrix!=0).sum(axis) 
  mask = countnonzero!=0
  output_mat = np.zeros(matrix.T.shape[axis])
  output_mat[mask] = matrix[:,mask].sum(axis)/countnonzero[mask] # line4
  return output_mat
```

Test the function

```
eachPSM = np.ones([5,4])
eachPSM[0] = 0
eachPSM[2,2:4] = 5
print each PSM
> [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  5.  5.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]]
ans = true_mean(eachPSM,0)
print ans
> [ 1.  1.  2.  2.]
```

However, if I want to calculate by row (`axis` = `1`), only `line4` has to change to

```
output_mat[mask] = matrix[mask,:].sum(axis)/countnonzero[mask]
```

Is there a way to flip `matrix[:,mask]` to `matrix[mask,:]` by using only number `0` and `1`? So I can have only one function for calculating true mean from row and column.

Comment: The laziest (but still fast) solution would be an `if` branching to `matrix[:,mask]` for `axis=0` and `matrix[:,mask]` for `axis=1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that the `[]` operator takes a tuple as input argument:

```
indexer = [slice(None), slice(None)]
indexer[axis] = mask

print(x[indexer])
```

`slice(None)` is equivalent to `:`, so we construct a tuple that takes the full matrix `[:, :]` and replace the entry of the desired axis with the mask.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
mask = np.array([True, False, True])

for axis in [0, 1]:
    indexer = [slice(None)] * x.ndim
    indexer[axis] = mask    
    print(x[indexer])
```

prints

```
[[0 1 2]
 [6 7 8]]
```

and

```
[[0 2]
 [3 5]
 [6 8]]
```